# Javascript e.preventdefault only for one element?

Tags: javascript, web-deployment, preventdefault

Hi i want to add a "read more" and a "read less" button to my website. Works great for one element but the problem is that when I have more then one element both open and close when I click on only one Button. Can Somebody help pls ? The result isn't working on this page idk why if u want to see the url of the website it's https://haushaltsautomatisierung.de/saugroboter-mit-wischfunktion/ Thanks for help !

```js
<script>
$("#readmore_01").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
    $("p").toggle("fast");
    window.scrollTo(170, 170);
    let name = $(this).html();
    $(this).html("Read less");
    if(name == "Read less"){
        $(this).html("Read more");
    }

 });


 $("#readmore_02").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
    $("p").toggle("fast");
    window.scrollTo(170, 170);
    let name = $(this).html();
    $(this).html("Read less");
    if(name == "Read less"){
        $(this).html("Read more");
    }

 });


</script>
```

```css
.wrapper{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns:2fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.img_01{
    grid-row:1 / span 1;
    grid-column: 1 / span 1;
}

.box{
    background-color:#d1d1d1;
}

.box_01{
    grid-row:1 / span 1;
    grid-column:2 /span 1;
      margin-right:15px;
    background-color:#d1d1d1;
}

.box_02{
    grid-row:1 / span 1;
    grid-column:3 / span 1;
    background-color:#d1d1d1;
}

.content_01{
    grid-row:2 / span 1;
    grid-column: 1 / span 3;
      margin-top: 20px;
      background-color:#d1d1d1;
}

.toggleBtn_01{
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ff7c26;
  font-size:115%;
user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;
}

.toggleBtn_01:hover{
    color:white;
}

.more_content_01{
    display:none;
    grid-column:1 / span 3;
    background-color:#d1d1d1;
    grid-row:3 / span 1;
    position:relative;
}



.img_02{
    grid-row:3 / span 1;
    grid-column: 1 / span 1;
    margin-top:20px;
}



.box_03{
    grid-row:3 / span 1;
    grid-column:2 /span 1;
    margin-right:15px;
    margin-top:20px;
    background-color:#d1d1d1;
}

.box_04{
    grid-row:3 / span 1;
    grid-column:3 / span 1;
    margin-top:20px;
    background-color:#d1d1d1;
}

.toggleBtn_02{
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ff7c26;
  font-size:115%;
user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;
}

.toggleBtn_02:hover{
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="content_01" id="content_01">
        
        <div>Das ist ein toller Saugroboter</div>
        <p style="display:none">Das ist mehr content </p>
        <div class="toggleBtn_01" id="toggleBtn_01">
        <i class="fa fa-plus" id="readmore_01"> Read more</i>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="content_02" id="content_02">
        <div>Das ist der zweite tolle Saugroboter</div>
        <p style="display:none">Das ich noch mehr content</p>
        <div class="toggleBtn_02" id="toggleBtn_02">
        <i class="fa fa-plus" id="readmore_02">Read more</i>
        </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="box_01">
        <p>DIE ERSTE BOX</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box_02">
        <p>DIE ZWEITE BOX</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box_03">
        <p>DIE DRITTE BOX</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box_04">
        <p>DIE VEIRTE BOX</p>
        </div>
        <div class="img_01">
        <img src="https://haushaltsautomatisierung.de/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/test.png">
        </div>
        <div class="img_02">
        <img src="https://haushaltsautomatisierung.de/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/test.png">
        </div>
        </div>











    



<script src="https://haushaltsautomatisierung.de/wp-content/themes/bam-child/js/main.js" defer="defer"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `$("p").toggle("fast");` <--- so you wonder why this selects everything???

Comment: damn was focused on that preventDefault.... my bad sorry

Comment: but thank you very much